# Angular material can I inject MatBottomSheetData or MatDialogData in the same component?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I need that same component would inject either `MatBottomSheetData` , either `MatDialogData` (in mobile `MatbottomSheetdata`, in desktop `MatDialogData`).

**So for example for desktop it works like this :**

```
export class DialogDataExampleDialog {
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData) {}
}
```

**And for mobile  :**

```
export class SheetDataExampleDialog {
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_BOTTOM_SHEET_DATA) public data: any) {}
}
```

**How to combine it to one so I dont need to seperate components ?**

My try was :

```
 @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA || MAT_BOTTOM_SHEET_DATA) public data: any
```

But it works only for the first `MAT_DIALOG_DATA`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out , here is how I am using the same component for MatBottomSheet and MatDialog :

```
  @Inject(WindowService.isDesktop && MAT_DIALOG_DATA || WindowService.isMobile &&  MAT_BOTTOM_SHEET_DATA) public data: any) {
    console.log('works in mobile and and desktop', this.data);
   }
```